# How many $p$-sets (that is, subsets with $p$ elements) of $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ in which: at least one of the elements $a_1,$ $a_2$ figure?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many $p$-sets (that is, subsets with $p$ elements) of $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ in which: at least one of the elements $a_1,$ $a_2$ figure?

**Attempt:** We have that, within the total of $2^n$ subsets, there is one with $p$ elements. We will have the case where only $a_1$ appears: $\displaystyle \binom{n-1}{p-1}$, which is the same result for the case where only $a_2$ appears. Adding all this to the case where $a_1$ and $a_2$ appear we have: $$2 \binom{n-1}{p-1} + \binom{n-2}{p-2}$$

I'm right?

Comment: I think it's fine.

Comment: This is not correct, as your $\binom {n-1}{p-1}$ terms would also count subsets containing both $a_1,a_2$.

Comment: Easiest is to work backwards and write $\binom np-\binom {n-2}p$ but if you want to use your approach, then the answer is $2\times \binom {n-2}{p-1}+\binom {n-2}{p-2}$.

Comment: Note that the "backwards" approach easily generalizes to the case of $k$ special elements (for you, $k=2$) whereas the "forward" approach becomes a rather messy sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

Your formula is incorrect as, after you have chosen whatever non-empty subset of $\{a_1,a_2\}$ you now must choose the rest from $\{a_3,\cdots, a_n\}$.  Thus you ought to have written $$2\times \binom {n-2}{p-1}+\binom {n-2}{p-2}$$

Alternatively, you could work backwards and write $$\binom np-\binom {n-2}p$$ as the complement of your collection is the subsets with $p$ elements chosen from $\{a_3,\cdots, a_n\}$

Comment: Thanks for the help, Lulu